# Node js Click with puppeteer an element that has no id or name

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Hi everyone I'm trying to click with puppeteer three elements that do not have an id, a name and a class; these are the checkboxes and the button that I have to click ([www.omegle.com](http://www.omegle.com)):

[image]

i tried to do it through the click with the coordinates but I can't center the elements to click:

```
  await page.mouse.click(50, 200);

  await page.waitForNavigation();
 })()
```

So is there a way to click on an element without knowing its id, class or name?

Comment: It may not have a unique id, but it certainly can be selected relative to other elements (for example, "first list item", or "second direct child of _other element_")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// open modal by clicking "Text" button
const btnText = await page.waitForSelector('#chattypetextcell img')
await btnText.click()

// click both checkbox labels when modal opens
const selectorCheckboxLabels ='div div p label'
await page.waitForSelector(selectorCheckboxLabels)
const labels = await page.$$(selectorCheckboxLabels)
await labels[0].click()
await labels[1].click()
```

Comment: great, it works, now I have to click the button that confirms (confirm and continue), the one after the checkboxes

Comment: I tried with this await page.click ('div div p input'); but i don't know why it uncheck the first checkbox